# Batch processing two sets of files

Tags: script, batch

Assume that I have two sets of files `foo_A_uid.bar` and `foo_B_uid.bar`. Each set contains (a known) number of files. Now, I want to process corresponding pairs using some tool (`ImageMagick` in my case), that is I want to run `some_command foo_A_i.bar foo_B_i.bar out_i.bar`, where `out_i.bar` is the result/output when running the tool on the pair `foo_A_i.bar` and `foo_B_i.bar` for some fixed `i`.

My question is how can I batch this process? Some `python`, `bash` script?

**Clarification:** By set of files I mean a list of files, all start with the same initial, then some UID and having the same extension. This hold for both input sets and the output.

Comment: When you say "sets of files" do you mean text files containing lists of files? So does "foo_A_i.bar" then mean "the ith line in file foo_A_i.bar"? If that's the case you can use the unix "paste" command to merge the two files side-by-side. And if that's not what you mean, I don't understand it.

Comment: By "set of files" I mean that I have two sets, each contains the same number of files. Each element of either of the sets is a file - `.png` in my case.

Comment: How long are those files? Will both lists of names easily fit into RAM? Are there filenames containing blanks and other, unusual characters like tab, line feed, page feed and so on?

Comment: The files in my case are binaries...

Comment: I was confused because it's not very clear from 'foo bar' style names you chose whether 'foo_A_uid.bar' was a text file containing file names (which I assume it is) or, for example, a directory containing the files. It's much clearer to use a name like 'file_list_A.txt' for a "set" and 'image_A_01.png" for a target file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, which works, although I don't know if it's a good one.

```
#!/bin/bash

EXPECTED_ARGS=3
E_BADARGS=65

if [ $# -ne $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
    echo Not the right number of arguments
    exit $E_BADARGS
fi

for i in $( ls $1* ); do
    TMP=$(echo $2$(echo $i | cut -d'_' -f2))
    TMP2=$(echo $3$(echo $i | cut -d'_' -f2))
    convert $i $TMP +append $TMP2
done
```

Running it should be something like:

```
script foo_A_ foo_B_ out_
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(wc -l foo_A_uid.bar)
for line in $(seq 1 ${count/ */})
do
    aline=$(sed -n $line"p" foo_A_uid.bar)
    bline=$(sed -n $line"p" foo_A_uid.bar)
    yourcommand "$aline" "$bline"
done
```

Assuming both files are sorted, the count-line get's the number of lines in file a.
Then a loop runs over all values from 1..count. The count-variable contains the name of the file, which is cut off with `${count/ */}`. With sed, you get the same line from both files. -n means 'no printing by default', $line"p" will then just print line $line.